# Help with output generated by this C code using fork()

Tags: c, fork

I am trying to figure out the output for a block of C code using fork() and I am having some problems understanding why it comes out the way it does. I understand that when using fork() it starts another instance of the program in parallel and that the child instance will return 0. Could someone explain step by step the output to the block of code below? Thank you. **EDIT: I FORGOT TO ADD THE EXIT(1) AFTER THE FOR LOOP. MY APOLOGIES.**

```
main() { int status, i;
         for (i=0; i<2; ++i){
             printf("At the top of pass %d\n", i);
             if (fork() == 0){
                printf("this is a child, i=%d\n", i);
             } else {
                 wait(&status);
                 printf("This is a parent, i=%d\n", i);
               }
          }
          exit(1);
}
```

Comment: ... And how *does* it come out?

Comment: Why don't YOU tell us the output and what is confusing about it.

Comment: Did you run it?  Since this is a test program, I would do that as the first step.  When you look at the output, you can easily infer what happened, can't you?

Comment: Should the first conditional not read: `if ((status = fork()) == 0){` instead - so that wait is actually waiting on the PID of the parent?

Comment: what I meant to say was that I want to predict the output before I run it.

Comment: I ran the program and this is the output created, I still got my prediction wrong, could someone explain the steps it goes through: I am sorry, I don't know how to format my comments :( 

 At the top of pass 0 
    this is a child, i=0
    At the top of pass 1
    this is a child, i=1
    This is a parent, i=1
    This is a parent, i=0
    At the top of pass 1
    this is a child, i=1
    This is a parent, i=1

Answer (score 1):

What happens on the first loop is that the first process forks. In one, `fork()` returns 0 and in the other it returns the pid of the child process So you'll get one that prints out "this is a child" and one that prints out "this is a parent". Both of those processes continue through the loop, incremement `i` to 1 and `fork()` again. Now you've got four processes: two children and two parents. All four processes will increment `i` to 2 and break out of the loop.

If you increased the loop termination condition to `i<3` then the next time around the loop all four processes will execute `fork()` and you'd have eight processes in total. If there was no limit in the loop, you'd have a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) where you'd just exponentially create more and more processes each loop until the system runs out of resources.

Comment: Hrm. I think I count 3 and 6 respectively. Maybe I need to actually run the code myself...

Comment: One minor nit.  *Both of those processes continue through the loop* is not quite correct; since the parent has called wait, only the child continues through the loop; the parent of that particular fork won't continue until the child exits.

Comment: Ah, 7 on the second run. But I see why.

Comment: @R Samuel Klatchko: Oh, you're right, I didn't notice the `wait()`.

Comment: So, in the first loop, when it forks, it does not equal zero, so it goes to the else and waits. Now in the new process created by the fork, it gets to fork() == 0, which should be zero right? since it's the child? so would it go to print "this is a child first" or would it go back to the first loop and cause it to print "This is a parent" and then it would print "This is a child"? After that would both processes go through the loop again, each one forking?

edit: Or does the Wait(&status) wait for the child to exit?

Answer (score 0):

This code can be tricky to explain.  The reason why is that the first child does not exit and will itself call fork.  Try modifying the code to include the process id on each print line such as:

```
printf("At the top of pass %d in pid %u\n", i, getpid());
```

Then notice how the child becomes the parent...